# C Operator Precedence with pointer increments

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I am trying to understand a line of C-code which includes using a pointer to struct value (which is a pointer to something as well).

## Example C-code:

```
// Given
typedef struct {
    uint8 *output
    uint32 bottom
} myType;
myType *e; 

// Then at some point:
*e->output++ = (uint8) (e->bottom >> 24);
```

Source: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6386#page-22

## My question is:

- What exactly does that line of C-code do?

Comment: @JimB the alternative meaning didn't make much sense either - can you perhaps elaborate on what it does do? (that way I can fix the title)

Comment: @Deduplicator thank you for pointing that out, I was usure whether or not it was too broad. Updated the question.

Comment: @Deduplicator just to be sure, this means that writing `*e.output = (uint8) (e -> bottom >> 24) + 1` does just the same?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66162/discussion-between-etienne-bruines-and-deduplicator).

Comment: all three operators, '*' '->' and '++' have the same precedence is C and have an associativity of left to right, so the line in question can be read from left to right, applying each operator in turn.  I.E. deref p, update address by offset to the output field, set the value being assigned. and finally increment.  However, it is much better to NOT make use of 'side effects' (in this case, the '++' is a side effect) in expressions

Answer (score 3):

"What exactly does that line of C-code do?"

Waste a lot of time having to carefully read it instead just knowing at a glance. If I was doing code review of that, I'd throw it back to the author and say break it up into two lines.

The two things it does is save something at e->output, then advance e->output to the next byte. I think if you need to describe code with two pieces though, it should be on two lines with two separate statements.

Comment: Unless there is a dramatic and dire need for optimization, the line of code does something that could be much more clearly expressed. Code is written once, read many times -- pity the reader and make it easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Deduplicator in the comments above, looking at an [operator precedence table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) might help.

- `*e->output++ = ...` means "assign value `...` to the location `e->output` is pointing to, and let `e->output` point to a new location 8 bits further afterwards (because `output` is of type `uint8`).
- `(uint8) (e->bottom >> 24)` is then evaluated to get a value for `...`

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
*e->output++ = (uint8) (e->bottom >> 24);
```

does the following:

1. Find the field `bottom` of the structure pointed to by the pointer `e`.
2. Fetch the 32-bit value from that field.
3. Shift that value right 24 bits.
4. Re-interpret that value as a `uint8_t`, which now contains the high order byte.
5. Find the field `output` of the structure. It's a pointer to `uint8_t`.
6. Store the `uint8_t` we computed earlier into the address pointed to by `output`.
7. And finally, add 1 to `output`, causing it to point to the next `uint8_t`.

The order of some of those things might be rearranged a bit as long as the result
behaves *as if* they had been done in that order. Operator precedence is a completely
separate question from order in which operations are performed, and not really
relevant here.