# C++ Operator Precedence with function pointer

Tags: c++, operator-precedence

```
class EventListener
{
public:
  const char* getName() { return name; }
  EventListener();
  EventListener(const string& n);

  void addTime(CrChkTime t) { time += t; }
  void resetTime() { time = 0; }
  CrChkTime getTime() { return time; }

private:
  virtual void dummy() {}

  const char* name;
  CrChkTime time;
};

typedef void (EventListener::*ftOnEventClass)(int kind, int param1, void* param2, bool& ret);

typedef struct _eventNode
  {
    /** For c handlers */
    ftOnEvent function;
    /** For c++ handlers */
    ftOnEventClass functionClass;
    /** Handle */
    EventListener* handle;

    /*...constructors...*/
} EventNode;

vector<vector<EventNode *>> m_vEventHandlerList;
for(auto& iter : m_vEventHandlerList[kind])
{
    if(iter->handle != nullptr)
    {
         (iter->handle->*(iter)->functionClass)(kind, param1, param2, ret);
    }
}
```

so,

```
(iter->handle->*(iter)->functionClass)(kind, param1, param2, ret);
```

is function call and working code.
(and it might be a  function pointer)

please can you describe me with Operator Precedence of next expression?

```
(iter->handle->*(iter)->functionClass)
```

iter->handle and.. next? i cannot follwing the code.

(I want a description like https://stackoverflow.com/a/27283893/3818785 this)

Comment: It would be helpful if you give the types of the elements `iter` `handle` `functionClass` etc.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje , added.

Comment: `->*` is a C++ [pointer-to-member operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586205/what-are-the-pointer-to-member-and-operators-in-c) that deals with pointer-to-member type values. It doesn't seem to be used correctly here.

Comment: @n.m. even if full code, still makes no sense..?

Comment: I'm sorry there is a pointer to member here but it is not being ised correctly. See the linked question and answer.

Comment: @n.m. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Sorry again, it'sused correctly after all, but it's obscure and misleading. Should have used more parens: `(iter->handle) ->* (iter->functionClass)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what happening (I simplified it to a workable example https://ideone.com/g8IL8s)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


class EventListener
{
public:
    void test(int n)
    {
        std::cout << "n is: " << n << std::endl;
    }
};

typedef void (EventListener::*ftOnEventClass)(int n);

struct EventNode
{
    ftOnEventClass functionClass;
    EventListener* handle;
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<EventNode *> m_vEventHandlerList;
    EventListener el;
    EventNode en = { &EventListener::test, &el};
    m_vEventHandlerList.push_back(&en);

    for (auto& iter : m_vEventHandlerList)
    {
        if (iter->handle != nullptr)
        {
            (iter->handle->*iter->functionClass)(123);
        }
    }
}
```

According to the rules of [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) member access `->` has precedence over pointer to member `*->` So here is the order:

- A. `iter->handle` gets handle pointer `EventListener*`
- B. `iter->functionClass` gets member function pointer
  `ftOnEventClass`
- C. `(A*->B)(123)` calls member function with the argument

Answer (score 1):

Since operator `->` has a higher precedence than `->*` (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), the following analysis holds:

```
(iter->handle->*(iter)->functionClass)
```

is equivalent to:

```
( (iter->handle) ->* (iter->functionClass) )
```

`iter->handle` has type `EventListener*`

`iter->functionClass` has type `ftOnEventClass`

So the whole expression is a pointer-to-member function dereference using the object pointed to by `iter->handle`.

The thing is, I don't see a member function in `EventListener` that has the argument list:

```
(int, int, void*, bool&)
```

So I don't see what `iter->functionClass` could be pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

```
iter
->
handle
->*
(iter)
->
functionClass
```

It's sooo clear, more clear than the link's question. Access members from `iter` one by one.

If you are confused with `handle->*(iter)`... `->` and `->*` are almost same except `->` accepts a member name and `->*` accepts a pointer.

If you are confused with the parenthesis, because the precedence of operator `->` and `*` is greater than `->*`.

Answer (score 0):

I recalled [**C++ Operator Precedence**](http://www.enseignement.polytechnique.fr/informatique/INF478/docs/Cpp/en/cpp/language/operator_precedence.html) from cppreference.com:

- `operator->` has precedence 2 (higher)
- `operator->*` has precedence 4 (lower).

and both are left-to-right (although, IMHO, this doesn't play a role here).

That means, in

```
(iter->handle->*(iter)->functionClass)
```

`operator->` is solved first, `operator->*` afterwards.

I.e. the above expression is equivalent to

```
((iter->handle)->*((iter)->functionClass))
```

Please, note that identifier `iter` is a bit misleading. `iter` is not an iterator (and `iterator` has a quite distinct meaning for containers and arrays).
Instead, the `auto&` in `for (auto&`... provides a reference to the current element (for each element in container after `:`). (May be, I'm a bit hair-splitting – sorry.)

I was a bit worried about the double occurrence of `iter` in the expression in quest. Hence, I tried to complete the sample code of OP to make it an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
// The following things have been added to make this an MVCE

#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct CrChkTime {
  CrChkTime(int) { }
  CrChkTime& operator=(int) { return *this; }
  CrChkTime& operator+=(const CrChkTime&) { return *this; }
};

// sample code of OP:

class EventListener
{
public:
  const char* getName() { return name; }
  EventListener();
  EventListener(const string& n);

  void addTime(CrChkTime t) { time += t; }
  void resetTime() { time = 0; }
  CrChkTime getTime() { return time; }

private:
  virtual void dummy() {}

  const char* name;
  CrChkTime time;
};

typedef void (EventListener::*ftOnEventClass)(int kind, int param1, void* param2, bool& ret);

typedef struct _eventNode
  {
    /** For c handlers */
    // Excluded: ftOnEvent function;
    /** For c++ handlers */
    ftOnEventClass functionClass;
    /** Handle */
    EventListener* handle;

    /*...constructors...*/
} EventNode;

int main()
{
    vector<vector<EventNode *>> m_vEventHandlerList;

    int kind = 0, param1 = 0; void *param2 = nullptr; bool ret; // Missing.

    for(auto& iter : m_vEventHandlerList[kind])
    {
        if(iter->handle != nullptr)
        {
             (iter->handle->*(iter)->functionClass)(kind, param1, param2, ret);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Though, I still don't understand it in ful detail (I was too impatient to fiddle this out) – the compiler seems so. It compiles without complaints:

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0afba3a64ba322e7)</kbd>